# How can I print a page in landscape in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I print a page in landscape in javascript?

Answer (score 5):

At the most you can set

```
@page { size: A4 landscape }
```

in CSS

Take a look at

[CSS Print Profile](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-css-print-20030813/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think JavaScript can dictate how a user chooses to print the page.

You might want to think about first converting the page into `.pdf`, and allow the user to download that?

Answer (score 1):

You cant. You can prompt the print dialog with **window.print()**, and from the printer settings choose the printer landscape format.